# how can I assign a widget's settings when I put it on the home screen

Tags: java, android, widget

How can I open an Activity at the start of a widget to set the required settings?

The idea is to on putting a widget on the main screen to be able to define which i.e. the working database through an index.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start some activity right after put widget on screen, it's enough to define in the manifest with this intent-filter:

```
<activity android:name=".ConfigurationActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

then add android:configure entry in AppWidgetProviderInfo metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure=".ConfigurationActivity"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="50000" />
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine. Notice that the Activity in 'android:configure' must be declared with a fully-qualified namespace.

Comment: @LuisSousa If it helped you, please mark it as answer